# Typescript Boolean-Comparison gives wrong results

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a weird problem: in one of my classes there' s a readonly-property of type boolean. When I try to check this property I get unexpected results. Here' s a code-sample:

```
// vorgang is a reference to the class, isEK is the property
let test = this.vorgang.isEK;
// Just for testing
let test2 = test ? true : false;
console.log(test + ' -> ' + test2);
```

And here's the resulting output:

```
true -> true
false -> true
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think it's about using "+" to concatenate values. try: console.log(test,"-->",test2)

Comment: Is the content of `this.vorgang.isEK` a "String" as in `"true"` or `"false"`?

Comment: You can use `!!test` to get its boolean value. If test is undefined, it will return false, true otherwise.

Comment: try _let test2 = <boolean>test ? true : false;_

Comment: Thank you, guys, after some further investigation I found out that in fact test contains a string, though the property as well as (meanwhile) the variable are declared as boolean. I don' t know why this is possible, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

> It may happen in case of strings. Your `this.vorgang.isEK` might be a string.

If so, Just replace your line `let test2 = test ? true : false;` with `let test4 = test3 == true ? true : false;`, where ***== will only check the value but not the data type***.

Your working snippet would be similar to the following -

```js
// getting it static
let test = "false";
// Just for testing
let test2 = test == true ? true : false;
console.log(test + ' -> ' + test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a boolean property:

```
get isEK(): boolean {
  return this.art && this.art.netto;
}
```

The output is correct while my comparison doesn' t work. This is driving me mad.

Comment: You are new here :) . Please do not post an answer to comment another answer. It is not a forum. There is a link _"add a comment"_ below each answer. You can just comment an answer, or edit your question to add some additional information, then add a comment to indicate you have completed your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one possible explanation: at runtime, the `test` variable contains the string `'false'`.

```
let test = 'false';
let test2 = test ? true : false;
console.log(test + ' -> ' + test2); // false -> true
```

Try to use this code for the property `isEK`:

```
get isEK(): boolean {
  return this.art && this.art.netto ? true : false;
}
```

You can also check a variable type at runtime with:

```
console.log('Type of test:', typeof test);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried something similar within the getter, but it didn' t solve the problem. Meanwhile I found a function called isTrueProperty() in ionic-angular/utils/utils, which did the trick on consumer-side. But still I cannot understand why a boolean-property turns into a string without explicit typecast.

Comment: @DeddyH Because your "boolean property" is not a boolean at run time. A type declared with TypeScript doesn't ensure anything at run time. It is easy to fool the TS compiler. For example you could do: `let str = 'false'; let test: boolean = str as any;` → here the variable `test` is a boolean at compile time but a string at run time. In particular, you can have this problem each time you take a variable from a `JSON.parse()` result.

Comment: @DeddyH Additionally, the operator `&&` in JavaScript can be tricky. https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/25/the-and-and-or-operators-in-javascript

Comment: I see there is still much to learn left for me. I am quite new to JavaScript/TypeScript, usually I code in Pascal which is really strongly typed. But errors are there to be made once and then never again, am I right? :-)